# CSS animation does not working only in IE

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code,  It works fine in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Mobile WEB but I cannot make it work in IE.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 800;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body{
  background: black;
  font-family: Arial;
}

svg {
    display: block;
    font: 10.5em 'Montserrat';
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.splash{
 width: 100%;
}
.btn{
 color:white;
 padding-top: 20px;
 font-size: 3em;
}
.text-copy {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
    -webkit-animation: stroke-offset 3.5s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: stroke-offset 3.5s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: stroke-offset 3.5s infinite linear;
    animation: stroke-offset 3.5s infinite linear;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(1){
    stroke: #620975;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -1;
 -moz-animation-delay: -1;
 -o-animation-delay: -1;
 animation-delay: -1;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(2){
 stroke: #C52203;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
 -moz-animation-delay: -2s;
 -o-animation-delay: -2s;
 animation-delay: -2s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(3){
 stroke: #C52203;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: -3s;
 -o-animation-delay: -3s;
 animation-delay: -3s;

}

.text-copy:nth-child(4){
 stroke: #C52203;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
 -moz-animation-delay: -4s;
 -o-animation-delay: -4s;
 animation-delay: -4s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(5){
 stroke: #DE700F;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: -5s;
 -o-animation-delay: -5s;
 animation-delay: -5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stroke-offset{
 0% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes stroke-offset{
 0% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}

@-o-keyframes stroke-offset{
 0% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}

@keyframes stroke-offset{
 0% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}

}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="./resources/js/jquery/3.1.1.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="./resources/css/vjigsaw/remake.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>CoPuzzle</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: table;" align="center">
<div class="splash" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
    <symbol id="s-text">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%">CoPuzzle</text>
 </symbol>

 <g class = "g-ants">
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
 </g>
</svg>

 <div class="btn">PLAY</div>
 <div class="btn">OPTION</div>
 <div class="btn">LOGIN</div>
 </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is missing the CSS code you want to show. Please add it to the question, using the formatting tools provided.

Comment: Sorry,,, CSS added! You'll see it now.